# Laravel 10 Vue.Js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-component

How to install VueBootsrap on laravel 10?

**App Js**

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import '../sass/app.scss';

const app = createApp({});

import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
app.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);


app.mount('#app');
```

Added all the necessary properties. However, no components are displayed. Maybe something should be added?

**Vite config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
export default defineConfig({

    server: {
        //...
        https: false,
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost',
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    isCustomElement: (tag) => {
                        return tag.startsWith('ion-') // (return true)
                    }
                }
            }
        })

    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },

});
```

When launching any components, an error occurs: Failed to resolve component.